# Multiple columns name having a specific word need to return something in dax

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

If the column1 name has ABS approver it should return  approver.
If column2 has HTF Reader it should return Reader.
If Column 3 has POY Writer it should return writer and there are 23 such columns.

Initially I had unpivoted the table and written dax it worked but theres an issue with data modelling because the Dim tables had no connection and I was not able to slice and looking for this approach.

I am looking for something like this which returns the result in Return Column(F) :

[image: Table Sample Picture]

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerQuery in this case.
Start by creating Custom Columns/Conditional Columns :

```
if [ABS approver] = "member" then "Approver" else null

if [HTF reader] = "member" then "Reader" else null

if [POY writer] = "member" then "Writer" else null

if [MAX Contri] = "member" then "Contri" else null
```

Here is an example :

[image]
Then combine the results in the final column :

```
Text.Combine(
    List.Select(
        {[Approver], [Reader], [Writer], [Contri]},
        each _ <> null
    ),
    ", "
)
```

[image]

Comment: since there are 23 columns we need to add 23 conditions. Is there a way where we can use CONTAINSTRING? eg when the column name contains Approver it should show approver, if it has writer return writer, if its reader return reader else contri

Comment: Can you clarify more with some input data ?